# Borrar registros de diferentes tablas con un mismo campo, un id

Tags: php, sql, script, prestashop

Hola estoy haciendo un script en php para borrar de la base de datos de prestashop productos que estan desactivados masivamente. Lo tengo todo hecho pero para borrar lo tengo hecho rudimentario, es decir:

```php
$queryDelete = "DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id_product = ".$identificador.";";
```

pero como tengo 11 tablas que están relacionada en prestashop con el producto y su id pues tengo puesto 11 veces esa línea. encontré este codigo en este foro pero no me funciona

```php
$queryDelete= "DELETE $tabla, $tabla2, $tabla3, $tabla4, $tabla5, $tabla6, $tabla7, $tabla8, 
    $tabla9, $tabla10, $tabla11
      from $tabla
      join $tabla2
      join $tabla3
      join $tabla4
      join $tabla5
      join $tabla7
      join $tabla3
      join $tabla8
      join $tabla9
      join $tabla10
      join $tabla11
      where id_product = ".$identificador.";";
```

En cada tabla esta la tabla de prestashop que accedo y con el id que le paso en cada ciclo del foreach, pero no me lo borra así.
Alguna ayuda para hacer de mi código sea mas eficiente?
Saludos, gracias

Comment: ya tienen delete cascade all ?

Comment: no veo que tendra de ineficiente hacer 11 veces el delete, si al fin y al cabo es lo que hace la base de datos...

Comment: Podrías generar un trigger para que se ejecute al eliminar un registro.

Answer (score 0):

Sin entrar a usar recursos de la base de datos, como `CASCADE` o un `trigger`, lo estás haciendo de forma correcta.

Pero si usas la imaginación, hay una manera más eficiente.

Para eliminar de una tabla relacionada con la tabla `product`, estás contruyendo una consulta para eliminar los registros que coincidan con un determinado `id_product`. De forma que haces esa consulta para cada producto que elimines.

Pero ¿qué te parece eliminar aquellos registros cuyo `id_product` no exista en la tabla `product`? Para esto sólo necesitas una consulta:

```
$queryDelete = "DELETE FROM $tabla " .
    "WHERE id_product NOT IN " .
    "(SELECT id_product FROM " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product);";
```

Recuerda, esa consulta no la tienes que poner cada vez que elimines un producto en tu bucle, sino al final, cuando ya has terminado de eliminar los productos, pones esa consulta, para cada una de las tablas relacionadas con la tabla product. Osea, **una sola consulta de limpieza por cada tabla**.

Es una forma muy eficiente de hacer limpieza.